# Truncate middle of piped text and replace with ellipsis in one command

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a very long text stream, which is begin sent to `stdout`. In bash I can show the first few lines by running:

```
$ seq 1 5010 | head 5
1
2
3
4
5
```

or the end

```
$ seq 1 5010 | tail 5
5006
5007
5008
5009
5010
```

However I need to show the first 5 and last 5 and an elipsis in the middle ... So the output might look like

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
5006
5007
5008
5009
5010
```

I need to do this in a one-liner in stock bash. Is that possible? How?

Comment: `head -n 5 file; echo ...; tail -n 5 file` but, more seriously, use awk, print the first five lines, keep a sliding window of five lines and print them out at the end.

Comment: What output do you want when `file.txt` has only 10 or less lines?

Comment: The file will always have more than 10 lines. I'm getting the input via stdout, don't have access to a file directly.

Comment: @Schneems: Please edit that information into your question. It is an important clarification, so it should not be in a comment.

Comment: @Schneems: Ok, I edited the question to make it clearer. I hope that's ok with you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually edited the title to add STDOUT. Looks like a race condition and your edit over-wrote my edit. Either way works for me :)

Comment: @EtanReisner: By the way, the fact that `head` does not guarantee to only read the requested number of lines means that `head -n5;` might absorb quite a few more than five lines. Try with `seq 1862`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one bash (v4) solution:

```
seq 1 5010 | { mapfile -tn 5 a; printf "%s\n" "${a[@]}" ...; tail -n 5; }
```

On v3, the following should work (although it's a much longer line):

```
seq 1 5010 | {
  for x in 1 2 3 4 5; do IFS= read -r; echo "$REPLY"; done;
  echo ...;
  tail -n 5;
}
```

Comment: Cool, should have specified. I'm on `3.2.53` locally and `4.1.5(1)-release` in production. Just verified on production, works great!

Comment: @Schneems: v3 solution upcoming

Answer (score 3):

Perl:

```
seq 5010 | perl -0nE '@lines = split /\n/; say join "\n", @lines[0..4], "...", @lines[-5..-1]'
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
5006
5007
5008
5009
5010
```

Equivalent awk:

```
awk -v RS="" '{
    for (i=1; i<=5; i++) print $i
    print "..."
    for (i=NF-4; i<=NF; i++) print i
}'
```

This is Etan's suggestion. Way more memory-efficient than my solutinos:

```
seq 5010 | awk '
    NR <= 5 
    {l5=l4; l4=l3; l3=l2; l2=l1; l1=$0} 
    END {print "..."; print l5; print l4; print l3; print l2; print l1}
'
```

Comment: And yet your implementation of my suggested solution is much more elegant than mine would likely have been. =)