# How can I read first n and last n lines from a file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, head, tail

How can I read the first n lines and the last n lines of a file?

For `n=2`, I read [online](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139089/how-to-read-first-and-last-line-from-cat-output) that `(head -n2 && tail -n2)` would work, but it doesn't.

```
$ cat x
1
2
3
4
5
$ cat x | (head -n2 && tail -n2)
1
2
```

The expected output for `n=2` would be:

```
1
2
4
5
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139089/how-to-read-first-and-last-line-from-cat-output

Comment: Also, the link you sent is not helpful because I do not know the range really. I am looking for a simple solution for this

Comment: Interestingly, `cat x | (head -n2 && tail -n2)` doesn't work but `(head -n2 && tail -n2) < x` does. I'll have to meditate a bit on why that is.

Comment: What would the expected output be if the input file was 3 lines long? Would it be `1 2 3` or `1 2 2 3` or something else? What if it was only 2 lines long - would the output be `1 2 1 2` or `1 1 2 2` or `1 2` or something else?

Comment: I edited the question with expected output.

Comment: OK, now show the expected output for `n=3`, `n=5`, and `n=7` given that input file.

Comment: Well my file is has more number of lines than 2n. I am not quite sure what is the answer to your question when you have less number of lines then 2n.

Comment: I don't think the `head && tail` trick is reliable. `head` from GNU coreutils behaves differently for pipes and regular files (source: the source), reading blockwise in one case but not the other. Depending on implementation details like that seems like a bad idea -- it's not guaranteed that `head` will leave everything it doesn't print for `tail` to work with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Truncate middle of piped text and replace with ellipsis in one command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158685/truncate-middle-of-piped-text-and-replace-with-ellipsis-in-one-command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are you're going to want something like:

```
... | awk -v OFS='\n' '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[1], a[2], a[NR-1], a[NR]}'
```

or if you need to specify a number and taking into account @Wintermute's astute observation that you don't need to buffer the whole file, something like this is what you really want:

```
... | awk -v n=2 'NR<=n{print;next} {buf[((NR-1)%n)+1]=$0}
         END{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print buf[((NR+i-1)%n)+1]}'
```

I think the math is correct on that - hopefully you get the idea to use a rotating buffer indexed by the NR modded by the size of the buffer and adjusted to use indices in the range 1-n instead of 0-(n-1).

To help with comprehension of the modulus operator used in the indexing above, here is an example with intermediate print statements to show the logic as it executes:

```
$ cat file   
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

.

```
$ cat tst.awk                
BEGIN {
    print "Populating array by index ((NR-1)%n)+1:"
}
{
    buf[((NR-1)%n)+1] = $0

    printf "NR=%d, n=%d: ((NR-1 = %d) %%n = %d) +1 = %d -> buf[%d] = %s\n",
        NR, n, NR-1, (NR-1)%n, ((NR-1)%n)+1, ((NR-1)%n)+1, buf[((NR-1)%n)+1]

}
END { 
    print "\nAccessing array by index ((NR+i-1)%n)+1:"
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        printf "NR=%d, i=%d, n=%d: (((NR+i = %d) - 1 = %d) %%n = %d) +1 = %d -> buf[%d] = %s\n",
            NR, i, n, NR+i, NR+i-1, (NR+i-1)%n, ((NR+i-1)%n)+1, ((NR+i-1)%n)+1, buf[((NR+i-1)%n)+1]
    }
}
$ 
$ awk -v n=3 -f tst.awk file
Populating array by index ((NR-1)%n)+1:
NR=1, n=3: ((NR-1 = 0) %n = 0) +1 = 1 -> buf[1] = 1
NR=2, n=3: ((NR-1 = 1) %n = 1) +1 = 2 -> buf[2] = 2
NR=3, n=3: ((NR-1 = 2) %n = 2) +1 = 3 -> buf[3] = 3
NR=4, n=3: ((NR-1 = 3) %n = 0) +1 = 1 -> buf[1] = 4
NR=5, n=3: ((NR-1 = 4) %n = 1) +1 = 2 -> buf[2] = 5
NR=6, n=3: ((NR-1 = 5) %n = 2) +1 = 3 -> buf[3] = 6
NR=7, n=3: ((NR-1 = 6) %n = 0) +1 = 1 -> buf[1] = 7
NR=8, n=3: ((NR-1 = 7) %n = 1) +1 = 2 -> buf[2] = 8

Accessing array by index ((NR+i-1)%n)+1:
NR=8, i=1, n=3: (((NR+i = 9) - 1 = 8) %n = 2) +1 = 3 -> buf[3] = 6
NR=8, i=2, n=3: (((NR+i = 10) - 1 = 9) %n = 0) +1 = 1 -> buf[1] = 7
NR=8, i=3, n=3: (((NR+i = 11) - 1 = 10) %n = 1) +1 = 2 -> buf[2] = 8
```

Comment: +1 since this works in a pipe. You might add a more elaborated version which takes files (streams) into account having less then 4 (head+tail) lines..

Comment: @EdMorton But it would still need to buffer the whole stream in memory.. (However I don't see a way without buffering if it should work in a pipe, except saving the stream into a temporary file)

Comment: Yeah, now it is not scalable for a large file. Still it works for me.

Comment: I wonder why cat x | (head -n2 && tail -n2) doesn't work... because this would be the perfect solution

Comment: You could keep just a running store of the last n lines you read. `tail` doesn't read from the beginning for regular files, mind you.

Comment: `awk -v n=2 'NR <= n { print; next } { delete lines[NR - n]; lines[NR] = $0 } END { for(i = NR - n + 1; i <= NR; ++i) print lines[i] }'` is what I was about to suggest. As a bonus, it doesn't print duplicate center lines in small files, although that wasn't a problem for OP. EDIT: Oh, I like the modulo idea.

Comment: To have a \n between lines: awk -v ORS='\n' '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[1]"\n"a[2]"\n"a[NR-1]"\n"a[NR]}'

Comment: I understand but the bug was just that I was setting `ORS='\n'` when I should have been setting `OFS='\n'`. Now that that's fixed there's no need to explicitly hard-code `"\n"`s between fields.

Comment: It struck me that the modulus logic using in populating/accessing the array contents might not be obvious so I updated my answer with an example that prints all relevant values as they are used. Hope that helps now and possibly as a future reference for other examples.

Answer (score 10):

```
head -n2 file && tail -n2 file
```

Comment: UUOC. `head -n2 x && tail -n2 x`

Comment: @rici: that was easy to fix `:D`.

Comment: This won't produce the correct output if the file is 3 lines long or less.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work even if your file is longer than 4 lines, if a single `head` buffer is so long enough that there aren't enough lines left in the file for `tail` to work.

Comment: Try `printf '%s\n' one two three four | { head -n1 && tail -n1; }` -- you'll see the `tail` has no output, because `head` filled its buffer with the data that `tail` would need to have for correct operation.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;N;s/[^\n]*/&/2;Ta;2p;$p;D' file
```

This keeps a window of 2 (replace the 2's for n) lines and then prints the first 2 lines and at end of file prints the window i.e. the last 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a GNU `sed` one-liner that prints the first 10 and last 10 lines:

```
gsed -ne'1,10{p;b};:a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'
```

If you want to print a '--' separator between them:

```
gsed -ne'1,9{p;b};10{x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b};:a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'
```

If you're on a Mac and don't have GNU sed, you can't condense as much:

```
sed -ne'1,9{' -e'p;b' -e'}' -e'10{' -e'x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b' -e'}' -e':a' -e'$p;N;21,$D;ba'
```

#### Explanation

`gsed -ne'` invoke sed without automatic printing pattern space

`-e'1,9{p;b}'` print the first 9 lines

`-e'10{x;s/$/--/;x;G;p;b}'` print line 10 with an appended '--' separator

`-e':a;$p;N;21,$D;ba'` print the last 10 lines

Answer (score 2):

Print the first and last n lines

- For n=1:

```
seq 1 10 | sed '1p;$!d'
```

Output:

```
1
10
```

- For n=2:

```
seq 1 10 | sed '1,2P;$!N;$!D'
```

Output:

```
1
2
9
10
```

- For n>=3, use the generic regex:

```
':a;$q;N;(n+1),(n*2)P;(n+1),$D;ba'
```

For n=3:

```
seq 1 10 | sed ':a;$q;N;4,6P;4,$D;ba'
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
8
9
10
```

Comment: the generic regex works for any value of n, but the n=1 and n=2 versions are more efficient

Answer (score 1):

`awk -v n=4 'NR<=n; {b = b "\n" $0} NR>=n {sub(/[^\n]*\n/,"",b)} END {print b}'`

The first n lines are covered by `NR<=n;`. For the last n lines, we just keep track of a buffer holding the *latest* n lines, repeatedly adding one to the end and removing one from the front (after the first n).

It's possible to do it more efficiently, with an array of lines instead of a single buffer, but even with gigabytes of input, you'd probably waste more in brain time writing it out than you'd save in computer time by running it.

**ETA:** Because the above timing estimate provoked some discussion in (now deleted) comments, I'll add anecdata from having tried that out.

With a huge file (100M lines, 3.9 GiB, n=5) it's taken 454 seconds, compared to @EdMorton's lined-buffer solution, which executed in only 30 seconds. With more modest inputs ("mere" millions of lines) the ratio is similar: 4.7 seconds vs. 0.53 seconds.

Almost all of that additional time in this solution seems to be spent in the `sub()` function; a tiny fraction also does come from string concatenation being slower than just replacing an array member.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a shell that supports process substitution, another way to accomplish this is to write to multiple processes, one for `head` and one for `tail`. Suppose for this example your input comes from a pipe feeding you content of unknown length. You want to use just the first 5 lines and the last 10 lines and pass them on to another pipe:

```sh
cat | { tee >(head -5) >(tail -10) 1>/dev/null} | cat
```

The use of `{}` collects the output from inside the group (there will be two different programs writing to stdout inside the process shells). The `1>/dev/null` is to get rid of the extra copy `tee` will try to write to it's own stdout.

That demonstrates the concept and all the moving parts, but it can be simplified a little in practice by using the STDOUT stream of `tee` instead of discarding it. Note the command grouping is still necessary here to pass the output on through the next pipe!

```sh
cat | { tee >(head -5) | tail -15 } | cat
```

Obviously replace `cat` in the pipeline with whatever you are actually doing. If your input can handle the same content to writing to multiple files you could eliminate the use of `tee` entirely as well as monkeying with STDOUT. Say you have a command that accepts multiple `-o` output file name flags:

```sh
{ mycommand -o >(head -5) -o >(tail -10)} | cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [GNU parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_parallel). To print the first three lines and the last three lines:

```
parallel {} -n 3 file ::: head tail
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [dcaswell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453328/using-sed-to-get-the-last-n-lines-of-a-huge-text-file/18453366#18453366), the following `sed` script prints the first and last 10 lines of a file:

```
# Make a test file first
testit=$(mktemp -u)
seq 1 100 > $testit
# This sed script:
sed -n ':a;1,10h;N;${x;p;i\
-----
;x;p};11,$D;ba' $testit
rm $testit
```

Yields this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
-----
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
```

Comment: And while it works for files shorter than 20 rows, it seems to swallow the last line for files shorter than 10 rows. ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) script. Assuming there might be overlap of head and tail.

#### File `script.awk`

```
BEGIN {range = 3} # Define the head and tail range
NR <= range {print} # Output the head; for the first lines in range
{ arr[NR % range] = $0} # Store the current line in a rotating array
END { # Last line reached
    for (row = NR - range + 1; row <= NR; row++) { # Reread the last range lines from array
        print arr[row % range];
    }
}
```

Running the script

```
seq 1 7 | awk -f script.awk
```

Output

```
1
2
3
5
6
7
```

For overlapping head and tail:

```
seq 1 5 |awk -f script.awk


1
2
3
3
4
5
```