# how can i mask the middle line of a pem key in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed

how can I **mask** the middle lines of a PEM key in bash script
 
 I need to echo my pem key with mask(*) the middle lines through a bash script

for example:-

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

as

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIICyjCCAbICCQDrpZYh8et7yTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAnMQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
****************************************************************
iDpYDNYlr0JDVQqogskWjrnWOh0YcIJKgVtiTh2HDM5TdQgeXg4wv5IqLok0Tw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I tried with `awk` but it failed:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for(i=2;i<='15';i++) $i="*"}1'
```

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: tried with awk but its failed ```awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""} {for(i=2;i<='15';i++) $i="*"}1'```

Comment: You can't use single quotes inside single quotes. The number should not be quoted at all anyway.

Comment: But perhaps a better fix would be `'NR>2 && NR < 16 { gsub(/./, "*") } 1'` if you know the exact number of lines. To only print the first masked line, replace `1` with `NR<=3 || NR >= 15` for example. To cope with a variable number of lines, keep the last few lines in memory and print in the `END` block.

Comment: @PradeepChandran, How many lines you want to mask? All apart from 1st and last? Can you please confirm once?

Comment: Please update the question with real requirements. Your attempt implied you only need a solution for a 17-line file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '1p;1n;2p;2s/./*/gp;$!N;$!D;p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

Print the first and second lines, then replace every character of the second line by `*`'s and print that too.

Make a window of two lines throughout the remainder of the file and print it on the last line.

On reflection, a shorter solution:

```
sed 'N;2p;4s/\S/*/g;4P;$!D' file
```

does the same as the first solution but perhaps more cryptically.

Comment: it works with most of the pem keys but not working with single lined pem keys like ```ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAhs3/WTw+nYEXM9daoBUA9Z76tjJ1qXRVUEyc/XjxY7A4xnSd+IQeU9PItu2pu/jIeXUM1ksLdCoTPdqDTgrojQqjRNMjKrjDgp4BHSR5t0z2IYFbnkOmlp4t6CJ2XjfMMeBKnGa+tHpcZ+THJIVOK+KjdBEcwgoU3D7V++XDRrb9GvTMQTnwM0WPkHFqPyJfRaEyl89RVRhlQtseI08uCRRwZnxIzWeghoGGc0vfjvyFJud4YfEjP0wvd07XGPBg/ubJNdoPNS/73XdrS935vsBGZy20AjsHOjs7ZErqA46Ija2TWQXS7UUOLaSukYRNqFzh5A40ePuVAkuflnS+XAgtw== test```

Comment: fixed that issue, split the single line to multiple with fold command thanks for the help!!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Scenario 1: 17-line PEM file**

It looks like your file has a fixed amount of lines and you want to replace all lines from the third till the fifteenth one.

You may solve it with `sed`:

```
sed -e '3,15d' pemfile | sed -e  "3 i\\$(printf '*%.0s' {1..64})" > newpemfile
```

NOTES:

- `sed -e '3,15d' pemfile` - removes lines from the third through the fifteenth
- `sed -e  "3 i\\$(printf '*%.0s' {1..64})" > newpemfile`  - adds a 64-asterisk line as the third line and saves the file as `newpemfile`.

**Scenario 2: Replace all lines but the first/last between two delimiter lines with a line with hardcoded number of asterisks**

If your problem is replacing the lines between two delimiters you may use GNU sed solution like

```
sed -E "/^-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+$/{
    n;n;
    :a; N; /\n-+END CERTIFICATE-+$/!ba; s/.*(\n.*\n)/$(printf '*%.0s' {1..64})\1/;
}" pemfile
```

See [this online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/88WIkc)

Here,

- `/^-+BEGIN CERTIFICATE-+$/{` - matches a line like `---BEGIN CERTIFICATE----` and if found, the block commands are executed:

  - `n;n;` - read two lines, the last is in the pattern space
  - `:a; N; /\n-+END CERTIFICATE-+$/!ba;` - read all lines up to a line like `---END CERTIFICATE---` appending with newlines to the pattern space
  - `s/.*(\n.*\n)/$(printf '*%.0s' {1..64})\1/;` - replace the whole pattern space text with 64 asterisks and the last two lines (we remove all lines up to the last two here)
    }`

Comment: Great solution. Actually, you could combine this into one sed statement, correct?

Comment: Would pem file always have the same length? And only one cert in one pem file?

Comment: @Jotne yes if they have the same key size. No if key size varies.

Comment: @JohannesH.I did just check my works pem files on ubuntu and cert are on different size and also multiple cert in on pem file.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew it works for above pem key but i like to list all my pem keys with the mask, here  you hardcore the line number and star char count both will be different for other pem keys :(

Comment: @PradeepChandran The second solution does not have any hardcoded line numbers, it is based on the assumption there are always two or more lines between `START CERTITICATE` and `END CERTITICATE` lines.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew some pem keys did not have START CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE lines

Comment: @PradeepChandran Then what are the requirements?

Comment: requirements are in the question: print the first and last two lines of a file, replace the middle content by one line of stars. period.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using @WiktorStribizew's anser if the file is actually a fixed 16 lines long.

If it can vary (keys might have more or less bits), the simple way is to combine `head` and `tail`:

```
head -n2 key.pem ; echo 'XXXXXXX' ; tail -n2 key.pem
```

But if you're looking for a single command, take a look at this answer form a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48002163/2284641

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did find work on our `pem` files

```
awk '/-----BEGIN/ {f=2} f-->0; /-----END/' etc/auth/server.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID8jCCAhoCCQDGQsEmfeBvJTANBgkqhkiG6w0BAQsFADB/MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIF8jBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG6w0BBQwwDgQIpS+A9Ql+5uUCAggA
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII8ejCCAmICCQCNHBN8tj/FwzANBgkqhkiG6w0BAQsFADB/MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It prints the header and footer of all cert + first line of cert.

Not exactly whats requested, but should be ok for the purpose of hiding the cert, and works with multiple cert in same pem file and multiple length of cert.

Or this is more correct (no counting lines, only `awk`)

```
awk '/-----BEGIN/ {f=2} f-->0; /-----END/ {print "****************************************************************\n" p "\n" $0}  {p=$0}' etc/auth/server.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII8MjCCAhoCCQDGQsEmfeBvJTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB/MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
****************************************************************
WW/14Mz4
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIF8jBABgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wMzAbBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwDgQIpS+A9Ql+5uUCAggA
****************************************************************
d9k=
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MII8ejCCAmICCQCNHBN8tj/FwzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB/MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
****************************************************************
ZZc1oaC0PKSzBmq+TpbR27B8Zra3gpoA+gavdRZj
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

```
awk '
  /-----BEGIN/ {f=2}
  f-->0; 
  /-----END/ {print "****************************************************************\n" p "\n" $0}
  {p=$0}
  ' etc/auth/server.pem
```