# How can I mask 200 characters of each line in a file with 3000 long lines?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a fixed width text data file. Each line is 3000 characters long. I need to mask (change to 'X") all the characters between position 1000 and 1200. There are no delimiters in the file, each field is known by its position in the line.

If I only needed to change 10 characters I could use `sed`:

```
sed -i -r 's/^(.{999}).{10}(.*)/\1XXXXXXXXX\2/'
```

But writing a `sed` command with 200 `X`'s does not seem like a good idea.

I tried using awk, but it returns different values for some lines because of spaces in the data.

Comment: A duplicate of [how can i mask the middle line of a pem key in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59066801/3832970)

Comment: Have voted to re-open. It seems that the question (and all its answers) put forward as a dupe involves masking an entire line - the "middle" in that question refers to the middle lines of the file rather than the middle of *each* line in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But writing a sed command with 200 X's does not seem like a good idea.

Let's do it anyway, but script it:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{999}).{200}/\1'"$(yes X | head -n200 | tr -d '\n')"'/'
```

Because it just so happens that `1000 % 200 == 0`, I think we also could:

```
sed -E 's/.{200}/'"$(yes X | head -n200 | tr -d '\n')"'/6'
```

Comment: Playing around with what I learned from your answer and the "[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59066801/517724)" question I came up with this: `sed -r "s/(.{999}).{200}(.*)/\1$(printf 'X%.0s' {1..200})\2/"`

Comment: That's another good one! You can remove the trailing `(.*)` and the `/2` - it matches everything and substitutes for everything, can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

My go-to tools are, in order of increasing ability to get stuff done, `sed`, `awk` and `python`. You may want to consider stepping up :-)

In any case, this *can* be done in `awk` with some initial setup, something like:

```
BEGIN {x="XXXXXXXXXX"; x=x""x""x""x""x; x=x""x""x""x}
```

which gives you (10, then 50, then) 200 X's.

Then you can just fiddle with `$0`, which is the whole line *regardless* of spacing. Depending on what you actually meant by "between positions 1000 and 1200", the numbers below may be slightly different but you should get the idea:

```
{ print substr($0,1,999)""x""substr($0,1200) }
```

You can see how this will behave in the following snippet, replacing character positions 3 through 6 on each line:

```
pax> printf "hello there\ngoodbye\n" | awk '
...>    BEGIN {x="X";x=x""x;x=x""x}
...>          {print substr($0,1,2)""x""substr($0,7)}'

heXXXXthere
goXXXXe
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1{x;:a;/^x{200}/!s/^/x/;ta;x};G;s/^(.{999}).{200}(.*)\n(.*)/\1\3\2/' file
```

Prime the hold space with a string containing 200 `x`'s. Append the hold space to the current line and using substitution replace the intended string with the mask.